# Vincular timer a um botão

Tags: c++, button, timer

Olá, estou começando agora a programar em c++ e estou desenvolvendo um projeto da faculdade, trata-se de uma tabela periódica. Pensamos em utilizar um botão para cada elemento (118 no total). Meu objetivo é animar o botão para que quando o mouse passe por cima ele dobre de tamanho, para isso utilizei um `Timer`:

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        int x = 70;
        if(x <= 140){
            button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(x, x);
            x += 5;
        }else{ timer1-> Enabled = false;}
    }

    private: System::Void button1_MouseHover(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        timer1 -> Enabled = true;
    }
```

Eu tentei várias coisas, mas até agora não consegui automatizar esse processo, queria criar alguma função que vinculasse o evento do timer com o botão que eu quero animar, por exemplo:

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e, System::Windows::Forms::Button^ bt) {
        int x = 70;
        if(x <= 140){
            bt->Size = System::Drawing::Size(x, x);
            x += 5;
        }else{ timer1-> Enabled = false;}
    }
```

ou então algo como:

```
scaleUp(System::Windows::Forms::Button^ bt);

private: System::Void button1_MouseHover(System::Object^  sender,    System::EventArgs^  e) {
        scaleUp(button1);
    }
```

Como criar uma solução para o problema sem que envolva criar 118 timers?

Comment: a tag está errada, Isso aí não é C++, é aquele dialeto da Microsoft chamado "C++/CX" ou algo assim...

Comment: Provavelmente a solução mais simples seria vincular o mesmo evento MouseHover em todos os botões e dentro do código programado para o evento efetuar um cast do parâmetro sender de System::Object^ para System::Windows::Forms::Button^ utilizando dynamic_cast. Feito isto você pode chamar scaleUp passando como parâmetro o ponteiro do tipo Button.

Comment: Vou tentar isso, muito obrigado.